How to make sure images with dynamic source show up at exactly same time in React?
Basically I have 10 slides of double images that complement each other on a website.
I have a state in a component counter that increments every 3 seconds with
setInterval(this.incrementCounter, 3000);
incrementCounter() {
    if( this.state.counter === 10 ) {
        this.setState({ counter: 0 });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1});
    }
}

In my render function, I have 2 images that I want to render side by side depending on this counter:
<div className="first-block-picture">
    <img alt="" width={531} height={738} src={require(`./${this.state.counter}-1.jpg`)}>
    </img>
</div>
<div className="first-block-picture">
    <img alt="" width={531} height={738} src={require(`./${this.state.counter}-2.jpg`)}>
    </img>
</div>

Whenever the counter changes, it seems that the 2 images might or might not change at the same time. About half the time, the first image would load just a fraction of a second before the second image does.
How do I make sure the images both change at the same time? What is the best way to ensure they don't get fetched again every single time the state counter changes?
I tried the setting the images to eager loading but doesn't work.

Try preloading the images. Read more about it here. If this solves your problem, let me know, I will update the answer accordingly.
